# How to define some fields in Word document editable

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a word document. There are some empty space in my doc and I want to define some fields that cursor only stays at there and when pressed tab cursor will go to the next field.

Anyone have any idea?

Comment: what you want is a form

Answer (score 1):

Use Word's inbuilt functionality to create a "[Fillable Form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-fillable-form-39a58412-107e-426b-a10b-ac44937e3a9f)".

> To create a form in Word that others can fill out, start with a template and add content controls. Content controls include things like check boxes, text boxes, date pickers, and drop-down lists. If you’re familiar with databases, these content controls can even be linked to data.